# Convert curl request with array of objects to JS axios or fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios, fetch

i'm trying to convert this request :

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_links \
  -u sk_test_dsgsdgsdgsdgsdyhwetdshsdhsdhsdhsdh: \
  -d "line_items[0][price]"=price_1K7o9TFRZ3JYnODMxojDKSWp \
  -d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1
```

to axios request :
My array

```
const arrayOfPrices = [
    { price: 'price_1K7nrWFwZ3JYnODMD6Bb3SEy', quantity: 1 },
  ];
```

I have tried :

```
 console.log(
    new URLSearchParams({
      arrayOfPrices,
    })
  );
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_links',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`,
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: new URLSearchParams({
      line_items: arrayOfPrices,
    })
  })
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.data);
      return { status: 'fail', message: err.message };
    });
```

And more different sets but it doesn't work.

Comment: The curl call contains basic authentication with a user. The JavaScript code contains a bearer token.

Comment: @jabaa documentation of Stripe says to use bearer ... no error is retuned about Authentication.

Comment: You're asking about a conversion and that's a difference between both methods. Have you tried to use a network monitor like WireShark and compare the requests?

Comment: You can use this tool: https://curlconverter.com/#browser

Comment: @jabaa that done the trick , thanks.